# Javascript Array of objects Output

Tags: javascript

```
 var input =[
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"},
  {make:"TATA", model:"aria"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"800"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"wagnor"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"720d"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"}  
];

var output ={};
```

Explanation:

I want output like below like grouping of values based on same key without duplicating values(unique). Array of object. Here duplicate values must not appear. I have tried a lot of code but can't figure out the problem.

```
[object object]{  BMW:["320d","720d"],  Tata:['area']  Maruti:['800','wagonar'], }
```

Comment: Could you show an example of what the desired output should look like?

Comment: @nickzoum : {
 BMW:["320d","720d"],
 TATA:["aria"],
 Maruti:["800","wagnor"]
}

Answer (score 2):

As OP does Not want Duplicates in the output array:

ES6, version 1:

```js
const input =[
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"},
  {make:"TATA", model:"aria"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"800"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"wagnor"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"720d"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"}  
];

const output = {};

for (const {make, model} of input) {
  // create empty list if this is the first time we've seen this make
  output[make] = output[make] || [];
  // only add model, once (no duplicates in our list)    
  if (!output[make].includes(model)) {
    output[make].push(model);
  }
}  

console.log(output)
```

Alternatively, instead of `if (!output[item.make].includes(item.model)) { ...`,
You could use `if (output[item.make].indexOf(item.model) === -1) { ...`

ES5, version 2:

```js
input =[
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"},
  {make:"TATA", model:"aria"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"800"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"wagnor"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"720d"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"}  
];

output = {};

input.forEach(function(item) {
  // create a new list if this is the first time we've seen this make
  if (!output[item.make]) { 
    output[item.make] = [item.model] 
  }
  // only add model, once (no duplicates in our list)
  else if (output[item.make].indexOf(item.model) === -1) {
    output[item.make].push(item.model)
  }
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const input =[
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"},
  {make:"TATA", model:"aria"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"800"},
  {make:"Maruti", model:"wagnor"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"720d"},
  {make:"BMW", model:"320d"}  
];

const output = {};
const mem = {};

input.forEach((item) => {
  if(!output[item.make]) {output[item.make] = [] }
  if (mem[item.model] != item.make) {
    output[item.make].push(item.model)
  }
  mem[item.model] = item.make;
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This answer has duplicates in the final array, but the OP wants the array to have only unique entries.